# OpenLayers 3 Draw Interaction onFeature added event

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In OL2 I was able to do the following:

```
var drawControl = new ol.Control.DrawFeature(
    myLayer,
    ol.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
        handlerOptions: {
            sides: 4,
            irregular: true
        },
        eventListeners: {
            featureadded: function( e ) {
                // process features
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Is there a way to do access the features once added in OL3? What I am trying to do is project the features once they have been drawn. Ideally, I would project them before they are drawn if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// draw is an instance of ol.interaction.Draw
// when draw ended but the feature was not added yet to ol.source.Vector
draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
  console.info(evt.feature);
});

// vectorSource is an instance of ol.source.Vector
// added to source
vectorSource.on('addfeature', function(evt) {
    console.info(evt.feature);
});
```